# Is something wrong with Firebug and Firepath?

Tags: firefox, firebug, firepath

My Firebug and Firepath were working fine, but they just started acting strange. When I click on objects on webpage, and do Inspect Element, it just does nothing. I didn't update or do anything on firefox. Anyone else having similar issues?

Comment: Did you recently install any custom theme or skins ? My firefox used to behave very strangely after I added a custom skin...

Comment: Have you tried restarting the browser. I find if I leave it open for too long it gets really slow and occasionally doesn't work

Comment: I tried restarting the broswer as well.  It seems after the 1.8.0 updated it has become foobared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I tried the next release 1.8.1b1 and it still failed. I reinstalled 1.7.3 and its working again.  Here is the link:

[Addon Firbug 1.7.3 Download](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/downloads/file/123595/firebug-1.7.3-fx.xpi?src=version-history)

and the versions page:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/versions/

Answer (score 2):

It's ok now,firepath 0.9.7 is compatable with firebug 1.8